# Trivial solution to the Continuous Knapsack problem

Tags: greedy-algorithms

I am a bit puzzled as to why the continuous knapsack problem is a non-trivial problem

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_knapsack_problem

Using the terminology in the Wikipedia link above,

If the Knapsack had a capacity of $W$, couldn't we just pick $W/w_i$ of the material $i$ having the maximum value per unit weight $v_i$?

Comment: You don’t have an infinite supply of each material.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Briefly, the supply of each material is finite: there is only $w_i$ of material $i$. If $w_i < W$, then you cannot fill the knapsack just with material $i$.

In the continuous (or fractional) knapsack problem, we are given a bunch of materials $1,\ldots,n$. Material $i$ has weight $w_i$ and total value $v_i$. The goal is to pick $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n \in [0,1]$ such that $\sum_i \alpha_i w_i \leq W$ in a way which maximizes $\sum_i \alpha_i v_i$. Your suggestion of taking $\alpha_i = W/w_i$ (for the best material $i$) is only feasible and optimal if $W = w_i$. If $W > w_i$ then the choice isn't feasible – there is not enough of material $i$. If $W < w_i$, then the choice (probably) isn't optimal, since the knapsack will still have room left.